# ID Name as a special character not working why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, special-characters

I am trying to **set id name as special character** not working.but without special character it is working fine.

id name ***100*** is working.

but ***batch/100*** not working.

```
     function calculateSum(){

   var id_name='100';

   var id_special_chrs='batch/100';

   var total =document.getElementById("total").value;

   var sub =document.getElementById("sub").value;


    $("#"+id_name).val((total)-(sub ));
    $("#"+id_special_chrs).val((total)-(sub ));

    }

    <input type="text" value="500" id="total"> 
    <input type="text" value="500" id="sub"> 
   <input type="text" id="100" onKeyup='calculateSum("+id+")' >
   <input type="text" id="batch/100" onKeyup='calculateSum("+id+")'>
```

Comment: Have you tried escaping the special character? Use \\ before the special character. May that would work.

Comment: / is not a valid character for id. You can find a discussion about it here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: @noveyak: HTML5 allows almost any character in an ID.

Comment: id will be dynamic so any other idea???